# Best practices to keep dependencies up to date in Module::Install made Makefile.PL

Tags: perl, makefile, perl-module, prerequisites

A "[Module::Install-Makefile.PL](https://metacpan.org/pod/Module%3a%3aInstall)" normally contains several lines like

```
requires 'Hello::World'=> 3.141592654;
```

to define the minimum version of a projects prerequisites.

Especially when lots of packages change after updates and the development environment differs, I keep updating all `require` statements in my projects `Makefile.PL` manually (or with a self made script) to the currently installed versions to make sure, that users can run my distributions the same way I do.

Which is the best practice to keep those prerequisite definitions up to date?
What is the best mechanism to do this automatically?

Comment: IMO leave the prerequisite version at whatever you actually know is a prerequisite (so most often 0).  don't punish those that don't run with the same set of dependencies you do; do have a good enough test suite to catch any likely problems.

Comment: You know, dependency related testing seems to me kind of complex because of the huge variety of dependencies and their versions. My experience is, that testing catches the problems on the target system after passing on my environment. This leads in fixing the `Makefile.PL`. But this kind of dependency checking is the worst case, I think. Isn't it? ^_^ Tracing the version of each feature in its distribution is kind of complex, too. I'd rather assume backwards compatibility of most cpan distribution's features even though I know, that this is not always the case.